# Let $a> 0, b> 0$. Prove that: $\frac{{{a}^{2}}}{b}+\frac{{{b}^{2}}}{a}+7\left( a+b \right)\ge 8\sqrt{2\left( {{a}^{2}}+{{b}^{2}} \right)}$

Tags: inequality, radicals, fractions, substitution, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Let $a> 0, b> 0$. Prove that: $$\frac{{{a}^{2}}}{b}+\frac{{{b}^{2}}}{a}+7\left( a+b \right)\ge 8\sqrt{2\left( {{a}^{2}}+{{b}^{2}} \right)}$$
My answer is:
[image]

Please give other interesting answers.

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{a^{2}}{b}+ \frac{b^{2}}{a}+ 7\left ( a+ b \right )= \left ( a+ b \right )\left [ \frac{\left ( a+ b \right )^{2}}{ab}+ \frac{16ab}{\left ( a+ b \right )^{2}}-  \frac{16ab}{\left ( a+ b \right )^{2}}+ 4\right ]$$
$$\geq  \left ( a+ b \right )\left [ 8- \frac{16ab}{\left ( a+ b \right )^{2}}+ 4 \right ]= 4\left ( a+ b \right )\left [ \frac{2\left ( a^{2}+ b^{2} \right )}{\left ( a+ b \right )^{2}}+ 1 \right ]\geq  8\sqrt{2\left ( a^{2}+ b^{2} \right )}$$

Answer (score 1):

after squaring (all is positive) and rearranging and factorizing we get $${\frac { \left( {a}^{2}+18\,ab+{b}^{2} \right)  \left( a-b \right) ^{4
}}{{a}^{2}{b}^{2}}}
\geq 0$$ which is true.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a^2+b^2=2tab$.

Hence, we need to prove that
$$\frac{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+2ab}(a^2+b^2-ab)}{ab}+7\sqrt{a^2+b^2+2ab}\geq8\sqrt{2(a^2+b^2)}$$ or
$$\sqrt{2(t+1)}(2t-1)+7\sqrt{2(t+1)}\geq16\sqrt{t}$$ or
$$(t+3)\sqrt{2(t+1)}\geq8\sqrt{t},$$ which is true by AM-GM:
$$(t+3)\sqrt{2(t+1)}\geq4\sqrt[4]{t\cdot1^3}\sqrt{4\sqrt{t}}=8\sqrt{t}.$$
Done!

Comment: Your answer is very interesting. Thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome!